# How can I run Elasticsearch Python code on an online notebook platform like Google Colab?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have python code working on my computer.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{'host': 'ip', 'port': 9200}],
    http_auth=('name', 'username'),

)
```

where the ip is the host ip of the elasticsearch on which it is running.
I want to run this code on google colab or other online python notebook platform. What should I do for this.

Comment: Can you elaborate?